# Intersect Scala set with set of subtype

Tags: scala, generics

Why doesn't this function compile?

```
case class MyType(n: Int)
def intersection(s1: Set[MyType], s2: Set[_ <: MyType]) =
  (s1 & s2)
```

I get the following error:

> error: type mismatch;  found   : Set[_$1] where type _$1
>   <: MyType  required: scala.collection.GenSet[MyType] Note: _$1 <:
>   MyType, but trait GenSet is invariant in type A. You may wish to
>   investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: MyType`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>                (w & r)

Is there a simple way to "promote" the second argument to type Set[MyType] without using asInstanceOf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set` is not covariant on its type parameter.

So a simple solution is to convert to `List` (which is covariant):

```
def intersection(s1: Set[MyType], s2: Set[_ <: MyType]) =
    s1.toList.intersect(s2.toList).toSet
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `Set` is defined as `Set[A]`. It is *in-variant* and not co-variant.

`&` is defined as

```
def &(that: GenSet[A]): Set[A]
```

It expects and argument of type `Set[A]`. But you are instead providing `Set[_ <: MyType]`.

`Set[_ <: Mytype]` is co-variant to `Set[MyType]`. But as the declaration says that the argument should be in-variant i.e. `Set[MyType]`, hence the error.

PS: You can think of co-variance as type converting from narrow to broader. For ex: if `Dog` extends `Animal` and if you do `Animal a = new Dog()`, you have a Dog (narrow) converting to Animal (broader). Above it expects invariant type. i.e. if it expects `Animal`, you can only provide an `Animal` only. Another example is `java.util.ArrayList` which is in-variant.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, now I don't know why this statement typechecks correctly: Set(new Object()) & Set("string")

Comment: @tba That is a very good observation. I have asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029746/weird-behavior-of-function-in-set . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Set` is invariant, however there is a surprisingly simple workaround:

```
def intersection(s1: Set[MyType], s2: Set[_ <: MyType]) =
  s2 filter s1
```

Or, if one wants to get better type inference for the result type:

```
def intersection[X <: MyType](s1: Set[MyType], s2: Set[X]): Set[X] =
  s2 filter s1
```

Here `s1` is used as a function. Functions are contra-variant in arguments, therefore `s1.apply` of type `(MyType) => Boolean` is acceptable as `(_ <: MyType) => Boolean`.

Performance is the same as `intersect`, as `this filter that` is how is `intersect` implemented for `Set`.