# Weird behavior of & function in Set

Tags: scala, generics

`Set` is defined as `Set[A]`. It takes a *in-variant* parameter. Doing below works as expected as we are passing co-variant argument:

```
scala> val a = Set(new Object)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Object] = Set(java.lang.Object@118c38f)

scala> val b = Set("hi")
b: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(hi)

scala> a & b
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
 required: scala.collection.GenSet[Object]
Note: String <: Object, but trait GenSet is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
              a & b
```

But the below works:

```
scala> Set(new Object) & Set("hi")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Object] = Set()
```

Above as I see it, the scala compiler converts `Set("hi")` to `Set[Object]` type and hence works.

What is the type-inference doing here? Can someone please link to specification explaining the behavior and when does it happen in general? Shouldn't it be throwing a compile time error for such cases? As 2 different output for the same operation type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure, but I think what you're looking for is described in [the language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) under "Local Type Inference" (at this time of writing, section 6.26.4 on page 100).

> Local type inference infers type arguments to be passed to expressions of polymorphic type. Say *e* is of type *[ a<sub>1</sub> >: L<sub>1</sub> <: U<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> >: Ln <: U<sub>n</sub> ] T* and no explicit type
>   parameters are given.
>
> Local type inference converts this expression to a type application *e [ T<sub>1</sub>, ..., T<sub>n</sub> ]*. The choice of the type arguments *T<sub>1</sub>, ..., T<sub>n</sub>* depends on the context in which the expression appears and on the expected type *pt*. There are three cases.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> If the expression *e* appears as a value without being applied to value arguments, the type arguments are inferred by solving a constraint system which relates the expression's type *T* with the expected type *pt*. Without loss of generality we can assume that *T* is a value type; if it is a method type we apply eta-expansion to convert it to a function type. Solving means ﬁnding a substitution *σ* of types *T<sub>i</sub>* for the type parameters *a<sub>i</sub>* such that
>
> - None of inferred types *T<sub>i</sub>* is a singleton type
> - All type parameter bounds are respected, i.e. *σ L<sub>i</sub> <: σ a<sub>i</sub>* and *σ a<sub>i</sub> <: σ U<sub>i</sub>* for *i = 1, ..., n*.
> - The expression's type conforms to the expected type, i.e. *σ T <: σ pt*.
>
> It is a compile time error if no such substitution exists. If several substitutions exist, local-type inference will choose for each type variable *a<sub>i</sub>* a minimal or maximal type *T<sub>i</sub>* of the solution space. A maximal type *T<sub>i</sub>* will be chosen if the type parameter *a<sub>i</sub>* appears contravariantly in the type *T* of the expression. A minimal type *T<sub>i</sub>* will be chosen in all other situations, i.e. if the variable appears covariantly, nonvariantly or not at all in the type *T*. We call such a substitution an optimal solution of the given constraint system for the type *T*.

In short: Scalac has to choose values for the generic types that you omitted, and it picks the most specific choices possible, under the constraint that the result compiles.

Comment: Accepting answer due to the link specified: It explains well in the examples mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `Set("hi")` can be either a `scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]` or a `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Object]`, depending on what the context requires. (A `String` is a valid `Object`, of course.) When you write this:

```
Set(new Object) & Set("hi")
```

the context requires `Set[Object]`, so that's the type that's inferred; but when you write this:

```
val b = Set("hi")
```

the context doesn't specify, so the more-specific type `Set[String]` is chosen, which (as you expected) then makes `a & b` be ill-typed.

Comment: Yes. As I explained in question, I understand this behavior. But I wish to know when and under what circumstances does it do it?

Comment: I have edited the question to make myself more clear. Apologies for before.

Comment: @Jatin: Oh, I see. What threw me off was your use of the word "convert": I thought you were saying that one situation allowed a `Set[String]` to be converted to a `Set[Object]`, while the other situation did not; whereas the actual difference is that one situation involved a `Set[String]` while the other did not.