# Strange scala.collection.immutable.Set adding behavior

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Why this code doesn't work:

```
val xs = Set(1, 4, 8)
xs + 1.5

<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
found   : Double(1.5)
required: Int
          xs + 1.5
```

But this is OK:

```
val xs = Set(1, 4, 8)
xs.toSet + 1.5

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[AnyVal] = Set(1, 4, 8, 1.5)
```

So?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how [toSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Set) is declared:

```
def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B] 
Converts this immutable set to a set.
```

In short it returns a new `Set[B]` where `B` can be `A` or any super type of `A`.

In doing `xs.toSet + 1.5` you haven't explicitly declared the type `B`. Hence now the type inference falls in action to determine the type. It sees `xs` is set of type `Int` and `1.5` is a Double. Type Inference now tries to find a type that can take Double as an argument.

The only next common type of Int and Double is `AnyVal`. Hence `B = AnyVal` and you get a new result set as `Set[AnyVal]`. If you explicitly specify type, then it obviously fails i.e.

```
scala> xs.toSet[Int] + 2.4
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(2.4)
 required: Int
              xs.toSet[Int] + 2.4
```

For more reference: [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) §6.26.4. A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029746/weird-behavior-of-function-in-set).